# How to move/animate a single subclass object across the screen without moving the other subclasses?

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt, graphic

For my last assignment in Java I have to model some 'monsters' and make one of them move across the screen. To do this I need to use the Timer already implemented, (`timer = new Timer (50, monsterPanel)` en make it that the X-coordinate of the subclass `'MovingMonster'` (parent `'Monster'`) moves to the right of the screen. At the same time the OTHER subclasses, only "`SeeingMonster"` for now, DON'T move across the screen.

My guess is have to change the x-coordinate in the `void draw(Graphics g)` method of the MovingMonster, but I'm not sure how I would then link this to the `public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)` in the `class MonsterPanel`, if it even should be in the same listener.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is the full code of the project, runnable in any IDE.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.*;

class MonsterMania {
    MonsterPanel monsterPanel = new MonsterPanel();
    Timer timer;

    void createGUI() {
        // create the GUI on the event thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Monster Mania");
                frame.add(monsterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize( 600, 400 );
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                monsterPanel.setBackground( Color.DARK_GRAY );
                monsterPanel.addMonsters();

                timer = new Timer( 50, monsterPanel);
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main( String[] a ) {
        new MonsterMania().createGUI();
    }
}

class MonsterPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    ArrayList<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<Monster>();  // the list of monsters on the screen

    void addMonsters() {
        monsters.add( new Monster( 50, 40 ));
        monsters.add( new Monster (150, 200 ));
        monsters.add( new Monster (300, 300 ));
        monsters.add (new SeeingMonster (150, 50, Color.GREEN));
        monsters.add (new MovingMonster (400, 150));
    }

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        super.paintComponent( g );
        for (Monster monster : monsters) {
            monster.draw( g );
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        for (Monster monster : monsters) {
            monster.step( this );
        }

        repaint();
    }  
}

class Monster {
    int size = 50;
    int arcSize = 10;  // size of arc that defines roundedness of rounded rectangle
    int locx = 0; // x coordinate center (pixel coordinates)
    int locy = 0; // y coordinate center (pixel coordinates)
    Color fill = Color.YELLOW;  // inner color
    Color line = Color.BLACK;   // color of border
    int phase = 0; // phase in the animation, a counter of time steps

    Monster( int x, int y ) {
        locx = x;
        locy = y;
    }

    // update the monster because a time step has passed
    // the parameter monsterPanel can be used for getting information about the panel, e.g., the size
    void step( MonsterPanel monsterPanel ) {
        phase++;
    }

    void draw( Graphics g ) {
        // draw body
        g.setColor( fill );
        g.fillRoundRect( locx - size/2, locy - size/2, size, size, arcSize, arcSize );
        g.setColor( line );
        g.drawRoundRect( locx - size/2, locy -size/2, size, size, arcSize, arcSize );
        // draw mouth
        // every 5 time steps, mouth is changed
        if ( phase % 20 < 10 ) {
            int s = size/5; // size of closed mouth
            g.drawOval( locx - s/2, locy + size/6, s, s );
        } else {
            int s = size/3; // size of open mouth
            g.fillOval( locx - s/2, locy + size/6, size/3, size/3 );
        }
    }
}

class SeeingMonster extends Monster{
  Color eyecolor;


  public SeeingMonster ( int x, int y , Color color){
    super( x, y);
    locx = x;
    locy = y;
    eyecolor = color;
  }

  void draw( Graphics g ) {
    super.draw(g);
    int s = size/7;
    g.setColor(eyecolor);
    g.fillOval ( locx + 10, locy - 15 , size/5, size/5 );
    g.fillOval ( locx + -15 , locy - 15 , size/5, size/5 );
}
}

class MovingMonster extends Monster{


  MovingMonster( int x, int y){
    super(x,y);
    locx = x;
    locy = y;
  }
  public int getLocationX() {
    return locx;
  }




  void draw (Graphics g ) {
    super.draw(g);




  }
}
```

Comment: don't let all your instances 'step'

Comment: How would I exclude some of the instances?

Comment: by not doing this: for (Monster monster : monsters) {
            monster.step( this );
        } for instance

Comment: But that has to happen so all the Monsters have the open/close animation. I found out just now I can add another step in the subclass which does that AND changes to coordinates, which fixes it. Thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another approach to this would be to override the method `step` inside your `SeeingMonster` class and just make it do nothing.

```
class SeeingMonster {
    @Override
    void step( MonsterPanel monsterPanel ) {}
}
```

An even better approach for this would be to create an Interface `Movable` with a method `step`.

```
public interface Movable {
    void step(MonsterPanel monsterPanel);
}
```

Now you could implement this interface into your MovingMonster class where you could implement this method now.

```
class MovingMonster extends Monster implements Movable {
    @Override
    void step( MonsterPanel monsterPanel ) {
        ++phase;
    }
}
```

Now you could hold a seperate `List` only for instances of `Movable`

```
List<Movable> monsters = new ArrayList<Movable>();
```

You could create a seperate function that gets a Monster as parameter, and if the Monster actually implements the interface then you could add this Monster into your seperate `List`.

```
private List<Movable> movables = new ArrayList<Movable>();
private List<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<Monster>();
private void add(Monster monster) {
    monsters.add(monster);
    if (monster instanceof Movable) {
        movables.add((Movable)monster);
    }
}
```

now you could make your addMonster method look like this.

```
void addMonsters() {
    add( new Monster( 50, 40 ));
    add( new Monster (150, 200 ));
    add( new Monster (300, 300 ));
    add (new SeeingMonster (150, 50, Color.GREEN));
    add (new MovingMonster (400, 150));
}
```

In the end your `actionsPerformed` method would be able to only loop over the `Movable` instances, which are in fact `Monster` which are able to move.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    for (Movable movable : movables) {
        movable.step(this);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Wow! While I'm not familiar enough with interfaces to use this, I'm pretty sure it's the best solution to this problem. Thanks!